# How to post JSON object to server?

Tags: angular, mongodb, http-post

I could not find a solution to my problem, but feel free to link me something that could help. This is the complete `sign-up.component.ts` file.

I am currently using Angular 5 and a Mongo DB, but am very new to using both of them. I am trying to post a JSON object called `survey` in the `sendDataToServer` function. to my Mongo DB, but am receiving an error that states `Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
    at Array.SignUpComponent.sendDataToServer`. I have been told that Observables instead of promises should be used, but I do not know how to implement that and am open to ideas.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Model, SurveyNG, JsonObject } from 'survey-angular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
const surveyJSON = { ... } // the JSON object

export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {
    const survey = new Model(surveyJSON);
    /*also here, call with this*/
    survey.onComplete.add(this.sendDataToServer);
    SurveyNG.render('surveyElement', { model: survey });
}

    sendDataToServer(survey){
        alert('The results are:' + JSON.stringify(survey.data));
        this.http.post('DATABASE_URL_OMITTED',
        JSON.stringify(survey.data))
        .subscribe(
        (val) => {
          console.log('POST call successful value returned in body',
            val);
        },
        response => {
          console.log('POST call in error', response);
        },
        () => {
          console.log('The POST observable is now completed.');
        });
    }
}
```

Please help me figure out how to post the JSON object to the database.

Comment: shouldnt your method sendDataToServer be inside of your SignUpComponent? also you are not passing any paramters to sendDataToServer method: survey.onComplete.add(sendDataToServer);

Comment: survey.data wont work because survey is undefined

Comment: I found that solution on the web, the ``survey`` in ``survey.onComplete`` for some reason becomes the parameter for ``sendDataToServer`` and creates a filled alert box with a defined ``survey`` in ``sendDataToServer``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sendDataToServer function is defined outside of the Component class that you're injecting the `http` service into, that's why referring to this.http inside that function is not working. The function needs to be inside of your class definition.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-sign-up',
    templateUrl: './sign-up.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sign-up.component.css']
})

export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        const survey = new Model(surveyJSON);
        /*also here, call with this*/
        survey.onComplete.add(this.sendDataToServer);
        SurveyNG.render('surveyElement', { model: survey });
    }
    //using arrow method notation makes the `this` keyword behave better
    /*function*/ sendDataToServer=(survey)=>{
        alert('The results are:' + JSON.stringify(survey.data));
        this.http.post('DATABASE_URL_OMITTED',
        JSON.stringify(survey.data))
        .subscribe(
        (val) => {
          console.log('POST call successful value returned in body',
            val);
        },
        response => {
          console.log('POST call in error', response);
        },
        () => {
          console.log('The POST observable is now completed.');
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Now it states ``Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
    at Array.SignUpComponent.sendDataToServer``

Comment: Oh yeah, that's probably the magic of typescript's `this`, I'd try turning the method into an es6 arrow method, `sendDataToServer(){} ` to `sendDataToServer=()=>{}` styles. That forces `this` inside the method to behave in a somewhat predictable way.

Comment: Glad I could help :)